# Digital Ocean Kubernetes Wordpress edit Settings

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes

I have a question about Kubernetes Wordpress installation.

I already have Wordpress installed via "one click installation" from the digital ocean marketplace.
The Problem now is that I can't change settings like IP etc. Does anyone know how to do this? I already read that if I change the files itself it won't update after a restart. So how can I manage to permanently edit IP and add a Cache line to the `WP-Config.php`?

I hope you understand my question and anyone can help me. I am new to Docker, Kubernetes thing so yeah.

Answer (score 1):

If you check DO marketplace https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/wordpress-kubernetes, you can see it is using helm chart under the hood to deploy your wordpress application. I would then strongly advised you to check how helm works first before touching anything.

`This DigitalOcean Marketplace Kubernetes 1-Click installs WordPress and MariaDB onto your Kubernetes cluster via Helm Charts`.

In this repository, https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/wordpress you can see the `values.yml` file. Dig into it to tweak settings.

About the IP address, it probably uses a Load balancer with a random IP address assigned by default. Check in your DO admin panel, in the networking tab > Load balancer. You should see one created with Nodes assigned to it.

Best,